# ts-loader throws 'export default not found' warning when chained with custom loader

Tags: typescript, webpack, ts-loader

I've created a loader to turn an XML like syntax into a typescript class, but adding ts-loader to the config alongside throws `export 'default' was not found`. When I import my custom file type, the loader runs but the result is undefined.

At this point, I've refactored my loader to just return a hardcoded string containing a barebones typescript class to pass to ts-loader, but it still doesn't work. I've also made a separate typescript file that matches exactly what my loader returns just to confirm the syntax is correct; ts-loader compiles that just fine and I get what I expect.

here's what my loader is returning as of now:

```ts
export default class TestComponent {
    data: Object = {};
    message: String = "hello, world";
}
```

here's my webpack module rule for my custom file type:

```js
{
    test: /\.comp/,
    use: [
        { loader: 'ts-loader' },
        { loader: path.resolve(__dirname, 'core/compose-loader.js') }
    ],
    exclude: /node_modules/
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ended up solving this by adding a step in my loader to transpile the necessary typescript source myself using `transpileModule` from Typescript.

found [here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Using-the-Compiler-API)